# Error traversing a JSON element and getting its values

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have a JSON file, let's say, something like this ...

```
{
    ...{
     },
    "notifications": {
        "satisfactory_record":"satisfactory record",
        "invalid_token" : "Invalid Token",
        ...
    },
    "faq": {
        "title" : "Frequently asked questions",
        "questions": [
            {
                "title" : "What is...?",
                "content" : "This is..."
            },
            {
                "title" : "What is...?",
                "content" : "This is..."
            },
            {
                "title" : "What is...?",
                "content" : "This is..."
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

And well, I want to take the object `"faq"` and print the `"questions"` title and content in a page of `faq.php` using a loop or iterator:

```
<?php

echo "<ul>";

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('file.json'), true); // Array
$questions = $json['faq']['questions'];

foreach($questions as $question){

    echo "<li>";
    echo "<span>$question['title']</span>";
    echo "<p>$question['content']</p>";
    echo "</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";

?>
```

But it does not work, because it throws me the following error: 
`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

This is the result I want:

[image]

> Note: I am using an associative array instead of an object by collective agreement, please do not answer by telling me to convert the JSON to an object instead of an array.

Comment: Apparently, `$questions` is not an array. If you run it through `var_dump()`, what is its output?

Comment: If it turns out that it's `null`, and `$json` is `null` as well, you might have a parse error. [`json_last_error()`](https://php.net/json_last_error) could be useful in that case.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Yes, is null, but i dont know what is the problem

Comment: Did you use `json_last_error()`, as Rick suggested? Actually, `json_last_error_msg()` might be a better choice.

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r()` the whole array? It almost looks like `[faq]` is an element of another higher level array....

Comment: @ChrisWhite The message is Syntax error

Comment: OK, so it sounds like your JSON is invalid. If you need help fixing it, you can edit your post to include it.

Comment: After setting `$json`, add a block which tests for `$json === false` and then output errors, don't let it proceed to the `foreach` block.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Sorry, I'm not allowed to publish the full JSON, plus JSONLint (https://jsonlint.com) indicates that the JSON is completely correct

Comment: Try to use a different file, make it as simple as possible and still keep "faq" and "questions" in the structure, then see what happens. Is there anything else in the file, or just plain JSON? No comments or anything else?

Comment: @mike.k It's just JSON, there are no comments or anything else

Comment: I think your faq property is not in your array root.

Comment: If `json_last_error_msg()` is returning `Syntax error`, your JSON is invalid. Does the file contain anything other than JSON data? Or, if you `var_dump(file_get_contents('file.json'))` do you see *only* the JSON data?

Comment: @rickdenhaanI have already solved the problem, it was a simple comma that was repeated in the JSON

Comment: If you solve this please post an answer. If it was typo of comma then I recommend closing the question